# h5py reading raw data with escape characters

Tags: hdf5, h5py

Hi I want to read the hdf5 file data as it is written
[image: h5Views]

But when I read it with the following code I get the following output

**COde**

```
    hf = h5py.File('Json.h5', 'r')
data_read = hf.get("BinaryData_metadata")
rmdwrite = open("Test.json", "w")
rmdwrite.write(str(np.array(data_read)))
rmdwrite.close()
hf.close()
```

**Output**

```
[b'{\n\t"TestReport": {\n\t\t"TestName": "XYZ",\n\t\t"Description"................
```

How to get the exact output with the same formatting in my output file?

When I print with this

```
Data_arr = str(np.array(data_read))
Data_arr = repr(Data_arr)
```

I get

```
'[b\'{\\n\\t"TestReport": {\\n\\t\\t"Te................
```

OKey this is how I am writing the data via C++

```
        DataSpace dataspace(1, dimsf);                    //Creating Dataspace
    StrType datatype(PredType::C_S1);                //Creating Datatype of type char
    datatype.setOrder(order);                           //Data Store Order
    datatype.setSize(file_datastring.length());                            //Datalength
    datatype.setCset(H5T_CSET_UTF8);
    DataSet dataset = Hdf5::fileObject.createDataSet(WriteDataSet, datatype, dataspace);    //Create dataset
    dataset.write(file_datastring, datatype);        //Write to dataset
```

is there something here which is appending that extra `\`

Answer (score 0):

The solution which I found was

```
    hf = h5py.File(H5FileName, 'r')
    FileObj = open(OutFileName, "w")
    hf.get(H5DataSetName).value.tofile(FileObj)
    FileObj.close()
    hf.close()
```

This works perfectly

Regards.
Siddharth